# The meaning of "for" after the colon mark

Tags: meaning

What does "for" meaning in this sentence? I mean the word "for" after the colon mark.

> A second difference from Quine is also important: for the crux of the Legal Realist
>   position (at least for the majority of Realists) is that non-legal reasons (e.g., judgments of fairness, or consideration of commercial norms) *explain* the decisions.

Full text [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lawphil-naturalism/).

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, for can have the meaning of "because". You can blindly ignore it in the given example (because) it's just a copula connecting the two sentences. I'd say the author used non-legal reasons when opting for the colon, precisely because this use of for is somewhat irregular, not at all conforming to the regular accusative use of for. But it gives a nice doublette: "important for the crux" blended with "the crux is".

Comment: We get this same question, like, every single day.